# only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars graphing sin

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to graph multiple equations in the same graph. I am having trouble with this one

```
def data():
    #func 1 - noisy sin wave
    x = np.linspace(1, 10000)
    func1 = 100*(np.sin(x/1000*2*np.pi*5) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(x)))
    ...
```

I define all of of the equations in one function `data` which has the return line

```
return np.array([func1, fun2, func3])
```

I then plot using

```
plt.plot(data().T)
```

However func1 gives the error:

```
only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with `func1` or rather the issue is with the concatenation?Also how do you expect to graph a 1000 dimensional matrix?data? ie when you transpose the data, assuming all is correct, you will have 3 x 1000 matrix

Comment: @Onyambu It works for the other functions but they are simple functions for example `func2 = np.random.randn(10000)` There are all 10000 long. If I remove func1, all other functions graph fine.

Comment: Full traceback is needed.  Often this error is produced when a function expects a scalar parameter, such as axis or a plot parameter.  In other words using an array argument in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem is that your function outputs arrays of different lengths. It works for me when the lengths are the same, but if they differ you don't get the message

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
```

I would just do something like

```
function_data = data()
for data in function_data:
    plt.plot(data.T)
```

I would also use a list instead of an array as output from the function, since numpy arrays with differently sized columns or rows , as the error message point out, is deprecated. Numpy arrays are great, but lists of arrays can be useful in cases like these.

Comment: From my implementation they should be the same though. For example 'func2 = np.random.randn(10000)'. Both are 10,000.

Comment: The function call x = np.linspace(1, 10000) returns an array with 50 entries between 1 and 10 000, not 10 000 entries between 0 and 1. Linspace takes inputs (start, stop, num) where the default value of num = 50.